# Python API for Google Drive and Google Sheets

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

This [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en) gives the Sheets API for Java and .NET.  Is there a reference for the same using Python, specifically Python in GAE?

Comment: Did you see https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/drive/v2 ?

Comment: Thanks. My Googling skills are not up to par.

Answer (score 0):

For the Sheets API there's a note on the page you linked:

> Note: The [Spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/) in Google Apps Script is more
>   powerful than this API, and now can be accessed via the [Apps Script
>   Execution REST API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/). If you're not sure which API you need to use,
>   try Apps Script first.

At least the Apps Script Execution REST API has a [Python guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/python).

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a Drive api to be called from a web app (written in Python), ie the web server is the client to Drive. Basically, the web app saves some data to a Google Sheet so that it can be shared by lay users. My web app owns the Sheet (not the web user). Can Apps Script perform this role?